# Specify Xml index storage location in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, indexing, partitioning

Is there a way how to specify storage location in MS Sql Server?

I have a relatively small tabel with xmls (up to 2 GBs of data) and a primary and secondary XML indexes on this table. Those indexes takes few time more space than the underlying table.
Is there any way how to physically separate the table and indexes into two separate partitions?

I do not see any sucha n option in MSDN (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-xml-index-transact-sql):

```
CREATE [ PRIMARY ] XML INDEX index_name   
    ON <object> ( xml_column_name )  
    [ USING XML INDEX xml_index_name   
        [ FOR { VALUE | PATH | PROPERTY } ] ]  
    [ WITH ( <xml_index_option> [ ,...n ] ) ]  
[ ; ]
```

But I'm hoping there is some trick.

Comment: The table and indexes are always separate. That doesn't mean they are stored in different filegroups. Why are you asking? Do you have a performance problem? Or simply wonder what happens?

Comment: @PPanagiotis - Yes, I'm asking due to existing issue. Our prod. xml queries were slow, which was solved by moving the most important xmls to a table on ssd and xml indexing it. The table data is fairly slow, but space taken by xml indexes is multiple times larger than the space taken by xml and is filling up the ssd

Comment: then the question makes no sense. It's the *index on the SSD* that makes the query fast. If you move it on a slow disk, you'll have a slow query. Besides, if you want to perform a lot of queries you should probably replace the xml values with actual columns. What do the values look like?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The xml are user defined records - there is no option to turn them into unified relational schema. The goal of any index is to decrease the amount of I/O operations (seeks vs scans). It's nice to also have faster I/Os if possible, but less amount of I/Os is allways the ideal speed up method. Not sure what does not make sense here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Creating XML Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/create-xml-indexes):

> The filegroup or partitioning information of the user table is applied
>   to the XML index. Users cannot specify these separately on an XML
>   index.

However, if I understand it correctly, you should be able to move the XML column and all indices based on it into a separate filegroup by using the `TEXTIMAGE_ON` clause of the `create table` statement:

```
create table dbo.MyTable (
  Id int not null,
  XMLData xml not null
)
on [PRIMARY]
textimage_on [LARGEDAT];
```

The only drawback I see here is that all LOB-typed columns from the table will be placed on that filegroup, not just XML one(s).

**EDIT:**

You can use the `large value types out of row` option of the [sp_tableoption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-tableoption-transact-sql) to force LOB data types out of row even if their values are small enough to fit the table page.

Comment: Thanks for citing that part of documentation I somehow missed :-/. LOB is not for us in this scenario - as we have small xmls (and textimage applies only to records above some size - IIRC 8000 bytes) plus index would still stay on primary. However partitioning seems to be best alternative in this situation (keeping the latest records and it's index on ssd and rest on hdd)

Comment: @Jan if the XML values are small, why use XML at all? What do they contain? Why not add extra columns? As for `still on primary` no. You can specify a *different* filegroup with `ON [whatever]`.

Comment: @Jan you are right, but there is a workaround for this, as well. Updated my answer.